# How to get data in android from mysql using json when the query is not same all the time,

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

Suppose i have to show different data to different users according to there id so i need to pass the id to the php script but json is a fixed query process(i think) now for that what can i do???

Comment: Show a little more detail please. Like tables/json//query.

Comment: What is a fixed query process?

Answer (score 0):

use id for different users like that :

```
$.post( "ajax.php?user_id=1", function( data ) { 
     //
},"Json");
```

and handle this request on the backend for example (don't forget to sanitize $_GET['user_id'], it is just simple example )

```
$query = "Select * from users where users.id = $_GET['user_id'] ";
// your code and $result .....
echo json_encode($result);
```